# Save custom post data outside of default post form

Tags: custom-field, admin

I have some text inputs in my post editing screen.

I can't have them in the standard metaboxes and they are outside of the default post form.

```
<form name="post" id="post" action="post.php">
```

I need to pass data from my custom text inputs when I click on "publish/update" button.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: How are you adding them to the page?  Why can't you add them to a metabox? First thought would be that you would need to add them to form using javascript if you a good reason for not adding them within the default post form

Comment: I have to build this box of options which is placed next to the "screen options" tab on the top of the page (which is outside of the form).